# Read if string.startsWith() and stop the stream if the condition fails

Tags: java, java-stream, functional-interface

I get message with message-headers. See sample message below

```java
private static String sampleMessage() {
        return """
               message from arunmantics.com
               X-Origination-IP:19.1.1.1.1
               X-api-kEY=134SDGFSDG234234SDFSDF
               Your order 6798977 is delivered.
               This order's cost is 
               """;
    }
```

I have to process this string only if it starts with `message from arunmantics.com`. I am able to achieve this in imperative style. See sample code below

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = sampleMessage();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (message.startsWith("message from arunmantics.com")) {
            var beginIndex = message.indexOf("com")+3;
            message = message.substring(beginIndex,message.length());


            for (String currentLine : message.split(System.lineSeparator())) {
                if (!currentLine.startsWith("X-")) {
                    sb.append(currentLine);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb);

    }
```

But I would like to come out of this imperative coding style and move to Functional style.

I would like to do something like this

```java
message.lines()
       .filter(...)
```

But i could't exactly make a decision to stop the stream if it is not starting with `message from arunmantics.com`.

I used `findFirst()`, but as expected it gives me an Optional with that particular string alone and filters out rest of the strings.

Is this not achievable at all using Streams API ?

Comment: You can still check whether the string starts with "message from arunmantics.com" the same you did before. There's nothing "non-functional" about it.

Comment: Agreed. I was looking to have it as part of the stream pipeline

Comment: Side note: when `message.startsWith("message from arunmantics.com")` is `true`, then `message.indexOf("com")+3` is equal to `"message from arunmantics.com".length()`. But you didn’t check whether this prefix spans a complete line, so if there’s content after this prefix, your code would treat it like a line. But I’m not sure what your actual goal of splitting and re-joining really is. Apperantly, something like `if(message.startsWith("message from arunmantics.com")) message = message.replaceAll("^message from arunmantics.com.*|\\R(X-.*)?", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still check whether the string starts with "message from arunmantics.com" the same you did before. There's nothing "non-functional" about it.

> I was looking to have it as part of the stream pipeline

If you *really* want to do this as a chain, you could technically create a singleton stream, use a `filter` to essentially create an empty stream if the message doesn't start with "message from arunmantics.com", and then `flatMap` to the `lines`.

```
var result = Stream.of(message)
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("message from arunmantics.com"))
    // the above creates an empty stream if the condition is false
    // and everything below will effectively do nothing, and the result will be an empty string
    .flatMap(String::lines)
    .skip(1) // skips the "message from..." line
    .filter(x -> !x.startsWith("X-"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This really doesn't show the intent as clearly as using an `if`, and it's really not any better than just using an `if`, in my opinion.